# Taking element from one of several collections

Tags: c#, algorithm, collections

Imagine you have 3 lists of different items. You have to return item from one of these lists by index. Index is number from 0 to `Count(<all lists items>)`.

Example:

```
lists 1: 10 items;
lists 2: 5 item;
lists 3: 1 item;
```

So, index should be between 0 and 15. Item by index:

```
0: lists 1, item 0;
1: lists 2, item 0:
2: lists 3, item 0;
3: lists 1, item 1;
4: lists 2, item 1;
5: lists 1, item 2;
6: lists 2, item 2;
7: lists 1, item 3;
8: lists 2, item 3;
9: lists 1, item 4;
10: lists 2, item 4;
11: lists 1, item 5;
12: lists 1, item 6;
13: lists 1, item 7;
14: lists 1, item 8;
15: lists 1, item 9;
```

(sorry for complete results. It's for my own understanding check).

Which is the best way to:

- **Determine which lists to use?**
- **Which index from lists to use to get item?**

Possible solution:

1. Put all items from all lists into one big list. Every items in big list should contain: index of list; item (OR index of item) from the list;
2. When index arrives, simple return item from big list.

Comment: So you want to index items in a list rotation.  Sort of like RAID 0 with unequally-sized disks?

Comment: Yes. Sound like a RAID 0.

Comment: by "Which index from lists to use to get item?" you mean that you want to convert those small lists' index to the big  one? or the opposite way?

Comment: Index for small list and index of that list.

Comment: What is the requirement behind this question? sounds weird for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick solution. You can pass all lists and get their enumerators. Then iterate over enumerators while they can return some results

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateAll<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    var enumerators = lists.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator());

    while (enumerators.Any())
    {
        enumerators = enumerators.Where(e => e.MoveNext());

        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
            yield return enumerator.Current;           
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 17 };


foreach (int x in EnumerateAll(list1, list2, list3))
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Output

```
 1 12 17 2 13 3 14 4 15 5 16 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

Here is updated solution, thanks to @Rawling comments

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateAll<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    var enumerators = lists.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator()).ToList();

    while (enumerators.Any())
    {
        enumerators.RemoveAll(e => !e.MoveNext());

        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
            yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

And one hint - if you need to reference elements by index, then just call `ToList()` or `ToArray()`:

```
var items = EnumerateAll(list1, list2, list3).ToList();
var item = items[5];
```

Comment: Very nice. However, I'd prefer making `enumerators` a list and calling `RemoveAll` on it - as it is, I think you could end up with hundreds of "nested" `Where` enumerators.

Comment: It's working when all list contains the same type of data (like `int` in example). How such solution could be improved to return item from list of int, string and bool?

Comment: @MaximKorobov in this case you can't use strongly-typed results, thus common type of `int`, `string` and `bool` will be `object`. So, just make method non-generic. I.e. remove all `<T>` and use non-generic `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: Sure. Then how to understand from which collection item by index was taken? I'm asking cause object then should be cast to appropriate type.

Comment: @MaximKorobov you can use `dynamic` or check type of object with `typeof`. Depends on what you are going to do with results

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to enumerate the `lists`, just check if the `index` is less than the minimum list count (minCount ) multiplied by the lists length (`lists.Length`) if thats the case the value to retrieve is pretty straightforward, or else return the index from the lists excluding the lists with the minimum count (`minLists`) and adjust the index accordingly:

(Of course this works only if you have an array of `IList`s (or arrays))

```
public static T GetByIndex<T>(int index, params IList<T>[] lists){
    var minCount = lists.Min(l => l.Count);
    var minLists = lists.Where(l => l.Count == minCount).ToArray();
    if (index < minCount * lists.Length)
        return lists[index % lists.Length][index / lists.Length];
    else 
        return GetByIndex(index - minCount * minLists.Length, lists.Except(minLists).ToArray());
}

public static void SetByIndex<T>(int index, T val, params IList<T>[] lists){
    var minCount = lists.Min(l => l.Count);
    var minLists = lists.Where(l => l.Count == minCount).ToArray();
    if (index < minCount * lists.Length)
    {
        lists[index % lists.Length][index / lists.Length] = val;
    }
    else 
        SetByIndex(index - minCount * minLists.Length, val, lists.Except(minLists).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have N lists (L0, L1, .. Ln) with amount of items (N0, N1 .. Nn), and you want to return element from this structure at "master index" K.

If K < N then return element [0] from list number K (if you dont have empty lists lol).

If K <= N * Min (N0...Nn) then return element [(K - K % N) / N ] from list specified by L = K % N value (L0 for L = 1, L1 for L = 2, L2 for L = 0 in your example).

If K > N * Min (N0...Nn), you probably need to reduce K by length of list(s) that are to short, and reduce N by 1 for each such list.

Something like that, probably you will need to adjust some values via debuggin.